# Is neural network suitable for supervised learning where the data (inputs and outputs) are continuous?

Tags: neural-network, regression, cart, recurrent-neural-network, supervised-learning

I am working on a regression model with a set of 158 inputs and 4 outputs of glass manufacturing project which is a continuous process of inputs and outputs. Is the usage of Neural Net a suitable solution for such kind of regression models? If yes, I have understood that Recurrent Neural Nets can be used for time series data, which Recurrent Neural Net shall I use? If usage of NN is not suitable, what are the other types of solutions available other than Linear Regression and Regression Trees?

Answer (score 0):

Neural Networks are indeed suitable for continuous data. In fact, it is continous by *default* I would say. It is possible to have discrete I/O for sure, it all depend on your functions.

Secondly, it is true that RNN are suitable for time series, *in a way*. RNN are in fact suitable for *timesteps* more than *timestamps*. RNN are working by iterations. Typically, each iteration can be seen as a fixed step forward in time. This said, if you data is more like `(date, value)` (what I call timestamp), it may not be so good. It would not be absolutely impossible, but that's not the idea.

Hope it helps, start with simple RNN, try to understand how it works, then, if you need more, read about more complex cells.